# Remove numbers from CV bibliography using biblatex in Texshop

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, moderncv, texshop, bibdesk

I have a question in relation to my CV that I am working on in Texshop. The problem I have encountered is to do with the bibliography, which shows up numbered - like so [n]. I have been trying to create an unnumbered bibliography using the recommendation that I found on this site but it's not working.

I am using the bibdesk for the references and running the biber engine in Texshop

This is the code I used:

```
\usepackage[
   bibstyle=ieee
]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{cvreferences.bib}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\@biblabel[1]{}
\makeatother
```

---

```
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography[title=Publications]
```

Also, as it is a CV the documentclass is as follows:

```
\document[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}
```

Please note I am not an advanced user. 
I would really appreciate help because I have spent already so much time on solving this problem but I am making no progress.

Thank you.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: Thanks. Sure, no problem. 
`\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}`         
`\moderncvstyle{casual}`                             
`\moderncvcolor{blue}                               
`\usepackage[`
 `bibstyle=ieee`
 `]{biblatex}` 
`\addbibresource{cvreferences.bib}` 


`\makeatletter`
`\renewcommand\@biblabel[1]{}`
`\makeatother`


`\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry}`

`\begin{document}`

`\makecvtitle`

`\section{Education}`
`\cventry{}{}{}{}{}{}`


`\nocite{*}`
`\printbibliography[title=Publication]`

`\end{document}`

Comment: for my publications I use conference papers, articles, thesis etc. An example from my bib file looks like this: `@conference{Jungmann2006b,`
 `Address = {Lancaster},`
 `Author = {M. Jungmann},`
 `Booktitle = {First International Workshop of Physicality},`
 `Date-Added = {2014-12-27 19:06:16 +0000},`
 `Date-Modified = {2014-12-27 20:15:41 +0000},`
 `Editor = {Alan Dix},`
 `Keywords = {physicality},`
 `Month = {February 6-7},`
 `Pages = {26-28},`
 `Title = {Beyond Physicality: Towards a Phenomenological Approach in the Design of Embodied Interactions},`
 `Year = {2006}}`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Add the following lines in your preamble

```
\DeclareFieldFormat{labelnumberwidth}{}
\setlength{\biblabelsep}{0pt}
```

The first line is to print nothing in the label, the second to eliminate the spacing before the entries.

MWE:

```
\begin{filecontents*}{cvreferences.bib}
@BOOK{book1,
  author    = {John Doe},
  title     = {Title},
  publisher = {Publisher},
  edition   = {edition},
  year      = {year},
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}
\moderncvstyle{casual}
\moderncvcolor{blue}

\usepackage[
   bibstyle=ieee,
   backend=biber
]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{cvreferences.bib}

\DeclareFieldFormat{labelnumberwidth}{}
\setlength{\biblabelsep}{0pt}

\firstname{John} % Your first name
\familyname{Doe} % Your last name

\begin{document}

\makecvtitle

\nocite{*}
\printbibliography[title=Publications]

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Does it work if other style is used (say, author initials) instead of number?

Answer (score 1):

*apa* style creates unnumbered bibliography.

```
...
\usepackage[style = apa]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{<pub.bib>}

\begin{document}
...
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: Very true, as apa is a very specific author date style.